# I go this error while running npm run build:

Tags: npm, vite

PS C:\Users\NUGGET\Desktop\Laravel_Project\laravel_react_intergrato\guide-to-laravel-and-react> npm run build

> build
> vite build

failed to load config from C:\Users\NUGGET\Desktop\Laravel_Project\laravel_react_intergrato\guide-to-laravel-and-react\vite.config.js
error during build:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'vite' imported from C:\Users\NUGGET\Desktop\Laravel_Project\laravel_react_intergrato\guide-to-laravel-and-react\vite.config.js.timestamp-1711279888310-9d905b29b0c8f.mjs
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:918:18)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1148:11)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)

I have tried installing vite
'create-vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\NUGGET\Desktop\Laravel_Project\laravel_react_intergrato\guide-to-laravel-and-react
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-vite

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\NUGGET\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-24T11_28_50_883Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please include a [mcve], containing instructions how to reproduce that error. Also, you can use a search for the error message to get an idea what it's about. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].